# jquery fullcalendar : operation after data add

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When we add a event to [jquery fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/selectable.html) (in selectable mode)on click or selecting dates. How to read the added event in jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - after your comment i think you must use the select function:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    if (title) {
        alert('start:'+start+' end: '+end);
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay
        }, true // make the event "stick"
        );
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

Look at the fiddle here, it alerts start and end date, but you also have access to tile and allDay parameters.http://jsfiddle.net/SYBsq/

Comment: this one works for already added event(when you click that event). What I want is when you add a event in [selectable mode](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/selectable.html) by selecting a date(you can add any event there by just clicking on any date), read that event added for saving it through ajax.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicola, really appreciate your help.

Thank you.